# Create all combinations of summations given criteria in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, subset

I have a subset summation problem I cannot find the answer to. I am trying to write something in VBA for access that will take all combinations of summations within a certain criteria and place them in a table so I can match a different table to it. Right now I am more concerned with creating the table of combinations. First time I have asked a question sorry if I mess something up.

Example:

Access Table: ImpTable

Fields: ID, Year-Month, Name, Country, Quantity

I need to make every combination of summations where the country and Year-Month are the same. Yet keep track of what was included in the formula. If the new table was created and kept track of which ID's were included in the combination I can reference the original table for the name.

Expected Ending Table Results:

NewID, Year-Month, Country, SumQuantity, ComboName (ID's from original table)

Any help is appreciated.

Raw Data:

```
ID    Year-Month     Name      Country   Quantity
 1     2016-06      Person1      US         10
 2     2016-06      Person2      US         12
 3     2016-10      Person3      US          4
 4     2016-06      Person4      UK          5
 5     2016-06      Person5      UK          6
 6     2016-06      Person6      US          3
```

Desired Results:

```
NewID   Year-Month   Country   SumQuantity   ComboName
 1       2016-06       US          22          1,2
 2       2016-06       US          13          1,6
 3       2016-06       US          25          1,2,6
 4       2016-06       US          15          2,6
 5       2016-06       UK          11          4,5
 6       2016-10       US           4          3
```

Comment: This is exactly what PivotTables do in Excel. Find some tutorials on YouTube and give it a try. EDIT: just noticed it is for Access -- you can do that with `GROUP BY` clause in SQL.

Comment: Group by will give a summary, but it will not give all combinations. Please see the example where you want to see not only all of them added together but the different combinations (could be a combo of 2 rows, or 3 rows, or more and any combination of those).